# Rebuild mdadm RAID5 array with fewer disks

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a 4 disk RAID5 array, one of which is starting to fail according to smartd. However, since I'm using less than half the space on /dev/md0, I'd like to rebuild the array *without the failing disk*.

The closest scenario I've been able to find online has been [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794121), however it contains bits that don't apply to me (LVM volumes) and also doesn't explain how I go about resizing the partition after I'm done.

Please note I have backups of important data, but I'd like to avoid rebuilding the array from scratch if possible.

Update: Failing disk has since been kicked out the array, can I still do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the power of Google, which brought me to [this article](http://blog.stalkr.net/2009/10/reducing-number-of-devices-in-raid-5.html), it's possible to resize RAID5 arrays under Linux since `mdadm` version 3.1.something.

1. First shrink the filesystem (using `resize2fs -M`).
2. Use `mdadm ... --grow --array-size=` to resize the array *down* so that it's the correct size for three physical volumes.
3. Use `mdadm ... --grow --raid-devices=3 --backup-file=/tmp/backup` to change the number of devices in the array.

I have never tested this myself, and until now I didn't even realize this operation was supported.  So, I've learned something.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @larsks. Failing disk has since been kicked out of the array, so it's now or never! Will report back if it works.

Comment: @drjeep Did it work?

Comment: We'll never know ...

Comment: According to [this mdadm manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm), the grow option explicitly says it also handles shrink.  Thus it should work by design.  But be sure to shrink the file system first, before `mdadm`!

Comment: Can confirm it works, reduced from 10 drives to 5 for raid5 array (one of the drives failed). With additional step of disabling write-intent map, according to https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing

Comment: Tested with mdadm v3.4 and kernel 4.9.0-11-amd64 and can confirm that this works as advertised.

Answer (score -3):

There is no stable way to shrink RAID5 array. I tried larsks's answer. Rebuilding did not work. (Stalled at 0% of progress) And I lost my RAID array.