# Cancel `md --grow` operation

Tags: mdadm, md

I added drives to an md RAID5 array, and quickly realized that I forgot to create a partition as is best practice (something I’ve also learned from bitter experience). How can I cancel this operation and re-add them?

Right now I froze the rebuild. As a safe workaround I can let the rebuild finish, fail one and replace it, etc. But this would take a week. Would failing both now also work?

Note: There’s another question with a similar title, but the OP was looking to simply pause the operation and the answer explains how. Please don’t close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would not risk to undo a running RAID5 grow, especially considering that not having a partition table on some component devices is not such a great issue.

Let it finish and *if and only if* you really want a partition table on all disks, [shrink the array](https://serverfault.com/questions/528281/rebuild-mdadm-raid5-array-with-fewer-disks) and re-add the required disks.